# json i18n: lang: { string } vs. string: {lang}

Tags: javascript, json, internationalization, locale

I have to implement internationalization (german, english) with a webapp.
I see that the most common approach is to structure the translations in different files per language:

de.json
fr.json

and the just switch the datastore programatically.

This is equivalent to a datastructure like this:

```
i18n:
{
   de: {
      hello: "Hallo",
      save: "Speichern,
      ...
   },
   en: {
      hello: "hello",
      save: "save",
      ...
   }
}
```

This approach allows to easily hand out the translation files to different translators and then simply add the new translated file to the app.
However, I dislike that the keys need to be kept in sync. I.e. If I add a new keyword (e.g. "delete") and I do not have all translations at that moment I nonetheless need to make sure that I update all json files so I dont forget to get the translations at a later point.

I therefore thought the following structure might avoid this problem:

```
i18n:{
   hello: {
      de: "Hallo",
      en: "hello"
   },
   save: {
      de: "Speichern",
      en: "Save"
   }
}
```

What are the drawbacks of this approach? Why does everyone use the first method?

Comment: My first assumption would be that you would only be traversing 1 object, based on current locale, rather than (number of words) objects.

In most cases, the seperate languages are actually stored in different JSON files to lessen the payload. When you know the locale, there is no need to bring in every language in one json, just the one in question.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: performance.

firstly, the logical data structure is a matrix, not a tree. so each approach is equivalent in persistency.

secondly, i18n is almost a read-only data structure at runtime. the first approach makes it read fast because when locale is given only one lang is needed, and you probably need lots of keys at one time.

3rd, if you need add/modify keys at runtime, it is a relevantly a casual case than read and you probably operate one by one, each approach would be the same.